# с чего начать C++?

Tags: c++

Хочу попробовать себя в C++ подскажите с чего стоит начать какую-нибудь книгу или видеоуроки может. желательно для совсем "зеленых" в этом.
И стоит ли вообще в 2022 начинать его изучать(мало ли).
Такие вопросы уже есть но задам новый тк книжки сейчас устаревают быстрее чем их печатают.

Comment: Я вот не понимаю одного, почему все вопросы пишут с тем, а стоит ли в таком то году изучать? Язык си был создан в 1970х годах, и он по сей день живёт и его изучают, и он как бы то ни было востребован.

Comment: @Kotomi в том то и дело что ему в 2 раза больше чем мне и мало ли деду уже пора покой всякое бывает

Answer (score -4):

Начни с осознания проблемы. Что тебе нужно? Много денег? Новые знания\навыки? Качественное и углублённое понимание материала? Или просто надоело, что все вокруг программисты и они много зарабатывают? Нужно понимание разницы между азартом (под азартом подразумеваю быструю наживу) и тем, что действительно хочется.

Comment: Найти язык "по душе" конкретно для себя, пробовал js, python и Lua. Вроде классные но что-то не то всё-таки.

Comment: @КанистраКанистрова и что именно "не то"?

Comment: @Effex просто не нравится хочется попробовать что-то кардинально другое

Comment: @КанистраКанистрова, ладно

Comment: @КанистраКанистрова в таком случае всё зависит от платформы (Linux, Mac, Windows or Other) Но я бы начал с документации (её достаточно с головой), а в моём личном случае - у меня читать не получатеся поэтому я смотрю исключительно курсы\видео.